# Jersey Client: Array of Strings as param

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I have a restful webservice with method:

```
@GET
@Path("/get/{id}")
public Operation getData(@PathParam("id") String... id) 
{
    //some code
    return data;
}
```

I've noticed MultivaluedMap but this is for query parameters.

As you can see, here I can add only one id, not array of Strings. My goal is to add array as parameter.

```
 WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(getBaseURI()).path("get").path(id);
```

How  to (with client) pass array of Strings as paramater with jersey?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

In general I've solved this by just using a `Collection` with a `@QueryParam`.

Something like:

```
@GET
@Path("/get/")
public Operation getData(@QueryParam("id") Set<String> ids) 
{
    //some code
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to JAX-RS specification](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.5.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html), the only way to receive collection as @PathParam is to receive it as List of PathSegment.
Another approach is to join all your String with ';' and pass it as single String, then, on server side, split it.
Also. Maybe you could switch to @QueryParam? @PathParam wasn't designed to pass multiple values as single param.